# How to add RSVP button options in MailChimp template

Tags: mailchimp

I've created a party invitation template in MailChimp with an RSVP section within the body of the email that contains 3 buttons:

1. yes
2. maybe
3. no

I have also added a custom text field on the list called "RSVP".

Is there a way I can automate the user click event to automatically update the profile and target this field?

I realize I can add the *|UPDATE_PROFILE|* merge tag and send the user to a custom form where they choose their RSVP option, but ideally i want to bypass the form and handle the response using the buttons in the email body ONLY.

Is this possible?

Comment: They just added a way to add custom survey answers via merge tags. Might help. http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/send-a-simple-poll-to-subscribers#Add-a-Survey-to-a-Campaign

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, mostly. You can do most of what you want with survey tags. The result won't be put in your custom text field in your list called "RSVP", but you will still be able to make segments of your list based on who clicked a particular response, as described below.

Anywhere in your email, in a text portion, include the following:

```
*|SURVEY: 1. yes|*
*|SURVEY: 2. maybe|*
*|SURVEY: 3. no|*
```

When the recipient gets the email, they will see three links:

```
1. yes
2. maybe
3. no
```

These links will take them to a survey landing page. (You can edit this: in your lists page, click the drop down to the right of the stats button, then choose Signup Forms, and then choose Form Builder, then in the drop down choose Survey Landing Page)

After you send out the email, and some people have clicked some of your yes/maybe/no links, it's time to see the results.

Click on Campaigns at the top of mailchimp, then the View Report button to the right of the email you sent. Scroll down and you will see a box called Poll Information, and in this there is a link to View poll results. There you can see who clicked on which link.

You can also make a list segment based on Poll/Survey Activity, which lets you do things like see who all didn't pick any of your RSVP options, who did, and who clicked which one.